# How to always keep a ribbon tab open

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I am trying to make the ribbon always open, meaning one tab is always open.

I managed to create an initial tab, that opens when the page loads.
I used the following code to do it:

```
SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);

ribbon.Minimized = false;
ribbon.CommandUIVisible = true;

const string initialTabId = "Ribbon.Test";

if (!ribbon.IsTabAvailable(initialTabId))
    ribbon.MakeTabAvailable(initialTabId);

ribbon.InitialTabId = initialTabId;
```

I can't find a way to make it always open (disable closing).

How could i achive that in Shaprepoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can append your url with `InitialTabId=<RibbonID>`

Comment: I already did that, as it can be seen in the code. This way when Io pen the page, the tab is loaded, but the tab can be closed.